# Null Pointer Exception When Setting ViewPager for TabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a fragment that will contain two other fragments that can be accessed through a `TabLayout`

I have the following Kotlin code:

```
class TutorialFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val tutorialview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tutorial, container, false )

        tutorialview.tutorialViewPager.adapter = TutorialFragmentPagerAdapter(context!!, fragmentManager!!)

        //Null Pointer Exception on this line 
        tabBar.setupWithViewPager(tutorialview.tutorialViewPager)


        return tutorialview
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = TutorialFragment()
    }
}
```

My code crashes with the exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager)' on a null object reference
        at com.vedantroy.animefacekeyboard.home.tutorial.TutorialFragment.onCreateView(TutorialFragment.kt:23)
```

Update 1 -

As per the suggestion of Tuby,

I changed my code to:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    Log.d("KEYBOARD-APP","Inside tutorial fragment onCreate()...")
    val tutorialView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tutorial, container, false )
    tutorialView.tutorialViewPager.adapter = TutorialFragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager!!)
    tutorialView.tabBar.setupWithViewPager(tutorialView.tutorialViewPager)

    return tutorialView
}
```

However, although the fragment itself is now showing, the tabs are not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error clearly says the `TabLayout` is null

Try changing

`tabBar.setupWithViewPager(tutorialview.tutorialViewPager)`

to

`tutorialview.tabBar.setupWithViewPager(tutorialview.tutorialViewPager)`

Comment: Hmm.. I did that and the exception went away. However, the tabs themselves are still not showing.

Comment: You might be missing titles for tabs or there is something wrong inside xml layout

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons, android studio is not auto importing the library at the top, I suggest you do that manually.

add this as a top level declaration in TutorialFragment

```
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
```